# JSON Interpolation: Need to inject variables into a .json file from a .js file for a REST (POST)

Tags: json, node.js, mocha.js, interpolation, string-interpolation

**What I'm trying to do:**

1) Post to my API with my .json file (*that contains the entire body that I need*)

2) From within the .json file I want to use a variable like ${value} to then take that value from my .js file and replace the var in the .json file

- Currently using NodeJS w/Mocha. I have my API call (.js code below):

---

```
 // for brevity - I removed the other dependencies
 const jsonconfig_post = require('./POST.json'); // this is my .json file

describe('\nPOST <TO MY ENDPOINT> \n', function() {
    const apiBase = `<MY ENDPOINT>`;
    const cookieJar = request.jar();
    var nameDate = new time.Date();

beforeEach(function(done) {
    this.timeout(5000);
    common.verifyLogin(cookieJar, done); //calls my login code
});

it('POST 1: <MY ENDPOINT> - POST', function(done) {
    const title = 'NodeJS_Project';
    let requestBody = jsonconfig_post(title + nameDate);
    //NodeJS_Project is the Var name and nameDate is the appended date
    this.timeout(5000);
    const opts = {
        jar: cookieJar,
        uri: `${apiBase}/<MY ENDPOINT>`,
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application / json",
            "Accept": "text / json"
        },
        body: (requestBody), // POST to my API with this
    };
    request(opts).then(() => {
        opts.body = {};
        console.log(requestBody);
        done();
    }).catch(done);
  });
});
```

- My POST.json file - below. I want to take ${title} & replace that with what I have in my .js code - "NodeJS_Project".

---

```
 {
 "title": "${title}",
 "Id": "<SOME ID>"
 }
```

learning NodeJS/Mocha & really liking it so far. I can make this work outside of using the .json file - but the use of the .json file makes things SO much easier in terms of what the .js looks like e.g. simple and clean. This is a small example - the other POST calls have use a HUGE json body (many nested elements), so the use of the .json, in this case, is very valuable e.g replacing many variables/values in a .json file. I know this can work, I hope? I'm getting a 400 currently and can see that the JSON is not getting passed to the endpoint correctly -OR- I just get the variable ${title} posted (not what I want). Any help would be So immensely appreciated. 
note - I've tried a number of other approaches using JSON.parse/stringify etc. but that has failed -OR- I'm not using correctly (surely could be the case :)).
Thanks in advance
Cheers!
-E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to: altering a json **file**?
This is possible but I don't think that it is what you are trying to achieve.

What you want to achieve is clean code so you extracted your requestBody into an external file, right?

So what I think the way to go is here, is to create a javascript file (post.js) in which you create an object **jsonconfig_post** that you export

```
exports.jsonconfig_post = {
  title: '${title}',
  Id: '<SOME ID>',
};
```

So now you can import this object in your code like

```
const { jsonconfig_post } = require('./POST.js');
```

And this is an object that you can modify like this

```
const jsonconfigWithValues = Object.assign({}, jsonconfig_post, { title: 'NodeJS_Project' });
```

And now you have a json object that you can pass through the body of your request

Comment: Thank you so very much for the reply @horstenwillem! I'm trying out what you suggest. I'll reply with what I find &/or questions if I can't get things to work.

Comment: The above solution works GREAT! Thank you and @Terrtiary both for the quick replies. This post has been answered! Fantastic! 
-Cheers!
-E

Answer (score 1):

I maybe late in this flow, please bear with me.
I faced the same problem myself & write a little npm plugin [interpolate-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/interpolate-json).

```js
// declare library variable
const interpolation = require('interpolate-json').interpolation;
// or
const { interpolation } = require('interpolate-json');

// The json with a variable placeholder
var postJson = {
  title: '${title}',
  Id: '<SOME ID>',
};

// replace placeholders with values, passed as json
var postJsonWithValue = interpolation.expand(postJson, {
  title: 'My Favourite Title',
});

// If you have different placeholder variable baoundary, like `{{ title }}`
// you can set that as a option object in 3rd parameter
// (more details in plugin documentation)
var postJsonWithValue = interpolation.expand(
  postJson,
  {
    title: 'My Favourite Title',
  },
  { prefix: '{{', suffix: '}}' }
);

console.log(postJsonWithValue);
// output: { title: 'My Favourite Title', Id: '<SOME ID>' }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are going to have to read your JSON file in your Javascript code. Best way to do that is to use the built in `fs` module.

1. Import FS first:

   ```
   const fs = require('fs');
   ```

   Then load in the JSON from your file into a variable and store that JSON as a Javascript Object. It's important to not be confused by the fact that Javascript Objects and JSON are not the same thing. You can check that out [here.](https://medium.com/techtrument/javascript-object-vs-json-117965ea3dea)
2. To import the JSON file with fs, do something like this:

   ```
   var importedData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('POST.json', 'utf8'));
   ```

   You can read the file in asynchronously as well but I am going to assume you want to do everything synchronously for now.
3. Now you want to replace your placeholder data, just do so like you would a normal object. You aren't really replacing the value like a template, although you technically could traverse the object and search for strings with `${TITLE}` but we are going to do it the straightforward way here. Something like this:

   ```
   importedData.title = 'TITLE';
   ```
4. Now write that object back to your original file:

   ```
   fs.writeFileSync('POST.json', importedData, 'utf8' function(err) {
     if(err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   });
   ```
5. Now you can send your post request to your server with the new JSON file.

   ```
   it('POST 1: <MY ENDPOINT> - POST', function(done) {
       ...
   });
   ```

I used mostly general examples but this is basically what you are looking for. Let me know if you have any questions about implementing it.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the reply @Terrtiary! I'm trying out what you suggest. I'll reply with what I find &/or questions if I can't get things to work.